# Combine two 2D-arrays of dots to 3D-array of dots

Tags: numpy

I am trying to get familiar with numpy. I have not been really successful yet.

I have a set of 10 jpg (same shape, 99*72px) representing the decimal digits 0 to 9. I would like to arrange each two of them side by side to get a 3D-Block of dots representing the two digits

for example for " 8R
[image]"

What i already got, is the coordinates of the black pixels of the jpg written to a file.
If somebody knows how to continue, would be great to tell me.

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
buppop = np.get_printoptions()['threshold'] #save numpy printoptions
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

image = cv2.rotate(cv2.imread('zwei.jpg'), cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Set threshold level
threshold_level = 25

# Find coordinates of all pixels below threshold
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(gray < threshold_level))

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(coords, file=f)

np.set_printoptions(threshold=buppop) #restore numpy printoptions
```

Actually don't know how to continue. Normally i would replace black pixels by boolean "true" and all other by boolean "false". Then loop through the 3 dimensions x, y and z, verify if x and y are "true" for the two side by side digit-shapes, in this case add the appropriate value for the third dimension z and then write the coordinates of the dot to a file.

I suspect this can be done much smarter with numpy, but actually i have no idea how to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thx

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how you make `8R` if you only have the digits 0 through 9. Where does the `R` come from?

Comment: Has nothing to do with this. Just for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

No need for coordinates.
You can easily do that directly from the matrices.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Just to random examples of images
im1=np.array([
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
im2=np.array([
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

im3d = im1[None,:,:]*im2[:,None,:]
# im3d has 3 dimensions. 
# so does im1[None,:,:]. The "None" as first index means that an extra
# dimension is added as first ax, of size 1, to the two already
# existing one, of sizes 16 and 12
# so im1[None,:,:] is a 1×16×12 3d array
# Likewise im2[:,None,:] is a 16×1×12 array
# And broadcasting rules says that you can multiply (or do any element-wise
# operation) between two arrays if each axis size either match (3rd
# axis here, is 12 in both im1 and im2, so result has also size 12), 
# or one of the 2 combined element axis has size 1
# (and resulting axis has the size of the other)
# So im3d = im1[None,:,:] * im2[:,None,:]
# is a 16×16×12 array, such has 
# im3d[z,y,x] = im1[0,y,x]*im2[z,0,x]
# which is exactly what you want

# Demonstration
i,j,k = np.where(im3d) # list of coordinates where we find non-0 values in im3d
ax.scatter(i,j,k)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Which I can rotate (with the mouse. I mean, just a viewing choice) to get at one angle
[image]

Or with another angle of view
[image]

Note that this kind of gadgets (I forgot the name, but I know there is one name for this specific objects) was popular a while ago among 3d printing geeks.
But it has a restriction: the digits must cover the whole x and y axis. Said otherwise, if you project the digit on the x axis (so you collect all x such as at least one pixel (x,y) is not 0), then all possible value of x should be on (so ∀x, ∃y, such as `digit[y,x]`≠0). And likewise for y (so ∀y, ∃x, such as `digit[y,x]`≠0).
So, in terms for pixel array, in each digit image, you have no completely empty row, and no completely empty column.

That is not a very hard constraint. On most font, it is naturally the case for 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
But for 1 you have to cheat a bit, and make the serif (the bottom bar) unnaturally wide to meet the constraint.

Likewise, for letters, all capital letters but I are easy. For I, you must widen the top and bottom serif so that it looks like a 90° rotated H.

There is not way around this. It is not a method (python or math) problems. Simply, there can't exist a 3D object whose appearance looks like one plane image on one side, and one another on another, unless the whole spread of both x and y are entierely used by both.

Comment: thx chrslg. I would however prefer to get the coordinates ...
written to a file. I would like to propose them to interested people and give them the chance to use their own app to create the model.